# Dates Stored as Text

Tags: excel-2007

I have several columns containg dates stored as text so 01/04/1984 actually reads 840401 or 01/04/2001 010401.  How do I convert this so I can the use the dates to make calculations?

Comment: is it what you need: `=DATE(LEFT(A1,2),MID(A1,2,2),RIGHT(A1,2))`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2)&"/"&MID(A1,3,2)&"/"&IF(VALUE(LEFT(A1,2))>50,19,20)&LEFT(A1,2))
```

which assumes years 31-99 are 20th century and others 21st.